# ionic3: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for Facebook

Tags: facebook, ionic3

I have added declarations for Facebook like the following in relevant files as well as app.module.ts. However still see the issue mentioned in subject line. What should be the resolution.

```
import {Facebook,FacebookLoginResponse} from '@ionic-native/facebook';
```

By, the way, I am relatively new to ionic, but not new to programming at all. Also, I have checked all the preliminary suggested resolutions like: https://devdactic.com/10-ionic-problems/ and the ones that came up on stackoverflow. However, not able to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

1   Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/facebook
```

2   Add this plugin to your app's module

```
import { Facebook} from '@ionic-native/facebook';

...

@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    Facebook
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

3   in your Ts componant

```
import { Facebook, FacebookLoginResponse } from '@ionic-native/facebook';

constructor(private fb: Facebook) { }

...

this.fb.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
  .then((res: FacebookLoginResponse) => console.log('Logged into Facebook!', res))
  .catch(e => console.log('Error logging into Facebook', e));


this.fb.logEvent(this.fb.EVENTS.EVENT_NAME_ADDED_TO_CART);
```